# String index out of range: -1 как проверить range? Или как обойти ошибку?

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

Код не работает. Я думал из-за того что я запрашиваю класс на той странице где его нет. Проверка присутствия класса тоже не помогла.

```js
doc2 = Jsoup.connect(NewLine).timeout(18*1000).get();
Elements elements = doc2.select("span.price");
if (!elements.isEmpty()) {
 Element priceElement = elements.get(0);
 System.out.println("есть цена");
    doc2 = Jsoup.connect(NewLine).get();
 priceElement = doc2.select("span.price").get(0);
    Здесь ошибка---> float price = Float.parseFloat(priceElement.text().substring(0, priceElement.text().lastIndexOf(" ")).replaceAll(" ", ""));
 System.out.println("цена="+price);
}else{
 System.out.println("Отсутствует цена");
}
```

Вылазит ошибка как и раньше

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

NewLine можно принят за "https://www.layta.ru/ip-kamery/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто узнай какая длина строки

[priceElement.text().length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length())

Comment: Да действительно, только не priceElement.length(), А priceElement.text().length().
Спасибо!)

Comment: да да верно изменил